# silverlight dataform edit issue

Tags: silverlight, dataform

I have the following dataform:

```
     <toolkit:DataForm    Margin="0,15,0,0" Height="300" Width="400"
      Name="dfEdit" CurrentItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem,
ElementName=dgMydataGrid}" LabelPosition="Top" AutoGenerateFields="False" CommandButtonsVisibility="Edit, Commit, Cancel" AutoEdit="False" AutoCommit="False" BeginningEdit="dfEdit_BeginningEdit" EditEnded="dfEdit_EditEnded">
```

Everything is working fine, I press the pencil icon and the item turns to editable mode, I am able to update DB. The problem is that, after submitting dataform, the pencil is still disabled, even if I select any other item on the dataGrid.What could be the problem?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I entered the following

```
dfEdit.IsReadOnly = true;
```

I did it because I copied from another method where I had to disable dataform